pyproj Transform returns inf values
I am transforming x and y coordinates from NAD27 NM  EAST FTUS to lat long.
This code had worked in the past, but just tried it recently and it is not working. Any ideas what could be happening?
I am using the following code
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:32012', preserve_units = True) #nad27 NM EAST FTUS
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326' )
long, lat = transform(inProj,outProj, 712000, 478500 )

However, the code returns:
(inf, inf)
( Python 3.12.4, pyproj 3.6.1)

This may be a helpful reference: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/discussions/1409



conda install -c conda-forge proj-data made the trick! thanks!



Glad to hear that it worked!
